# Help on ruby methods with the same name

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am currently working through [http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/sign-in-sign-out#sec:current_use](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/sign-in-sign-out#sec%3acurrent_user)r][1](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/sign-in-sign-out#sec%3acurrent_user) and I am having trouble understanding what the difference between the two current_user methods. In my other method sign_in there is a called to self.current_user but I am having trouble understanding which current_user is called and what the other current_user method is actually doing.

```
module SessionsHelper
  def sign_in(user)
    cookies.permanent.signed[:remember_token] = [user.id, user.salt]
    self.current_user = user
  end

  def current_user=(user)
    @current_user = user
  end

  def current_user
    @current_user ||= user_from_remember_token
  end

  def signed_in?
    !current_user.nil?
  end

  private
    def user_from_remember_token
      # using the * makes us pass two values [id,salt]
      User.authenticate_with_salt(*remember_token)
    end

    def remember_token
      cookies.signed[:remember_token] || [nil,nil]
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `current_user=` method is called when you assign to the current_user attribute of your object, and the `current_user` method is called when you don't.

So `self.current_user = user` calls `current_user=` while `!current_user.nil?` calls `current_user`.

Comment: Would I even need the `current_user=` method if I am just calling `!current_user.nil?` ? Because doesn't the `current_user` method retrieve a user and or else just sets `@current_user` to nil.

Comment: @Kevin: If sign_in were modified to assign to @current_user, then you could drop the current_user= method in that code.  But you'd find current_user= to be useful if you wanted to create the ability to "impersonate" users - you're logged in as you but pretend to be someone else.  (This feature can help in debugging customer support issues.)

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that `current_user=` implements the equal operator. So when you do `current_user = something`, it is really calling `current_user=(something)`.

As opposed to `current_user`, which is just a 'getter'.

I'd read [this article](http://www.rubyist.net/~slagell/ruby/accessors.html) on Ruby Accessors.

Answer (score 0):

This is assignment method.

to be used like

`obj.current_user= some_user_object` calls following method.

```
  def current_user=(user)
    @current_user = user
  end
```

Following method returns the object current user. If @current_user is null it will assign the user object to it and return it.

`some_user=obj.current_user` calls following method.

```
  def current_user
    @current_user ||= user_from_remember_token
  end
```